# Webpack - typescript hot module reloading [awesome-typescript-loader]

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to add hot module reloading into my typescript project. I have the following settings:

**package.json**

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server"
```

**tsconfig.js**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "/public/",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
var sourceFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.tsx',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: publicFolder,
        publicPath: publicFolder,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'awesome-typescript'],
                include: sourceFolder,
            },
        ],
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
                include: sourceFolder,
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        colors: true,
        port: 3000,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        progress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

I get the following error message in my explorer:

> GET http://localhost:3000/public/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

It seems that the public path is wrongly defined. Please can you help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the file exist in your `/public` directory?

Comment: No, but I thought that webpack generate the bundle.js automatically when any change of code is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `output.publichPath` is incorrect. It should be an url: `publicPath: '/public/'`. Not a path on your local filesystem.

From the [webpack documentation](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath)

> The publicPath specifies the public URL address of the output files when referenced in a browser. For loaders that embed  or  tags or reference assets like images, publicPath is used as the href or url() to the file when it's different than their location on disk (as specified by path)

Webpack dev server will generate an in memory bundle and serve it from `output.publicPath`

From [webpack dev server documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

> This modified bundle is served from memory at the relative path specified in publicPath (see API). It will not be written to your configured output directory. Where a bundle already exists at the same URL path, the bundle in memory takes precedence (by default).